# EpiServer: Get IDs of items in content area

Tags: episerver

I'm workin on a view (Razor) of a block (blockA). This block contains a ContentArea called `solutions`. I would like to get a list as a string of the IDs of the items in `solutions`.

I have tried looking in `@Model.Solutions.FilteredItems.` or `@(((IContent)Model).ContentLink.` to see if I can access a list of the IDs of all the items.

How can I get the IDs of all items in `solutions` as a string list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the ID in the ContentLink of the ContentAreaItem, no need to cast

To output as a comma separated list,

```
// always null check contentareas in templates
var idList = Model.ContentArea != null && Model.ContentArea.FilteredItems.Any() ? string.Join(",", Model.ContentArea.FilteredItems.Select(x => x.ContentLink.ID)) : "";

<div>@idList</div>
```

To write it out as a list

```
@if (Model.ContentArea != null && Model.ContentArea.FilteredItems.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.ContentArea.FilteredItems)
            {
                <li>@item.ContentLink.ID</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, yes iterating through the list with ContentLink.ID makes perfect sense.

Comment: @BrokenCode depending on what you need yes :)